# firebase storage, retrieving an image to a vue app

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage, vuex

I am trying to download an image from my firebase storage to render it in my Vue app, the upload from the application to the firebase storage is successful, however upon retrieval it gives me an error, i am using the firebase SDK in a Vue CLI 3 setup and vuex to manage my state. Here is the function setting in my actions in the main store.js file

```js
createMeetUp({commit, getters}, payload) {
  //here my payload is an object contains the following props
  const meetup = {
    title: payload.title,
    location: payload.location,
    date: payload.date.toISOString(),
    description: payload.description,
    creatorId: getters.user.id
  }
  
  let imageUrl
  let key
  
  //now i am reaching out to the firebase database to store the above object
  firebase.database().ref('meetup').push(meetup)
  .then(data => {
    key = data.key
    return key
  })
  .then(key => {
    //also in my payload object i stored an image file
    //so here i am uploading the image to the firebase storage
    const fileName = payload.image.name
    const extension = fileName.slice(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'))
    return firebase.storage().ref('meetup/' + key + '.' +       extension).put(payload.image)
  })
  .then(imageInfo => {
  //the issue is here in this then() block as i am stuck on how to retrieve the image from the storage to render it in the app
    imageUrl = imageInfo.getDownloadURL()
    return firebase.database().ref('meetups').child(key).update({
          imageUrl: imageUrl
      })
  })
  .then(() => {
    //here i am simply commiting my mutation.. 
    commit('createMeetUp', {
      ...meetup,
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
      id : key
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
}
```

the error I am getting is:

> TypeError: imageInfo.getDownloadURL is not a function

Again I believe the issue is in the `then()` block where I retrieve the image from the firebase storage. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code. `fileData` doesn't appear anywhere in your question but `imageInfo` does

Comment: You're resolving the promise with the result of `.put()` which is an [`UploadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask). This does not have a `getDownloadURL` method

Comment: well, regarding the error message not matching the returned data from the promise, I just changed the name of the value from fileData to imageInfo after i saw the error, the issue is in the logic itself, Now, I understood your point that i am trying to resolve the promise with the result of .put() and that doesn't have a getDownloadURL method, i am it makes a lot of sense,but what is your suggestion in this case, and thanks very much for your fast response

Comment: The `then()` method of the `UploadTask` will return a `UploadTaskSnapshot`which has a `ref` property which, in turns, has a  `getDownloadURL` method. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks for your response, but i am still a little confused, so you are saying that the `put()` which is my `uploadTask` will return an `UploadTaskSnapshot` which has a `ref()` will have a `getDownloadURL` method, and this to my understanding is contradicting what @phil claimed that the `uploadTask` doesn't have the `getDownloadURL` method, i checked the link you attached, but i still unable to determine which part should i alter to get this working. :S

Comment: @SwilamMuhammad Have a look at my answer below. HTH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the comments above, the following should work if I am not mistaking (not tested...).

Note that `getDownloadURL()` returns a promise (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL)), therefore you have to chain the promises.

```
  ....
  .then(key => {
     //also in my payload object i stored an image file
     //so here i am uploading the image to the firebase storage
     const fileName = payload.image.name
     const extension = fileName.slice(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'))
     return firebase.storage().ref('meetup/' + key + '.' + extension).put(payload.image)
  })
  .then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
     return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
  })
  .then(imageUrl => {
    return firebase.database().ref('meetups').child(key).update({
          imageUrl: imageUrl
      })
  })
  ....
```

Comment: I am simply speechless, this little issue really got me to the core, I have been stuck with it since yesterday, I really can't thank you enough :) cheers :)